# Image and PDF file upload validation in PHP

Tags: php, image, validation, pdf

Im creating a web app that manages staff records, one of the features allows staff to upload copies of their qualifications. Because many scanners output into different file types i need to be able to validate that the uploaded files are either a PDF or one of the many different image file types.

Im aware of the MIME validation method and have used this but as it is relatively easy to hack I'm looking for a more secure method to supplement it with.

The relevant code from the config file where constants are stored

```
// Set the file types allowed to be uploaded
define('FILETYPEALLOWED', serialize (array ('image/pjpeg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/JPG', 'image/X-PNG', 'image/PNG', 'image/png', 'image/x-png' ) ));
```

The code that handles the form

```
    //If a file was uploaded, Move the uploaded file
    IF (isset($_FILES['upload'])) {

      $allowed = unserialize (FILETYPEALLOWED);

      $fileinfo = finfo_open (FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

      //IF file type is allowed
      IF (in_array($_FILES['upload'] ['type'], $allowed )) {

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload'] ['tmp_name'], UPLOADS . $_FILES['upload'] ['name'] );

      } else { 
         //Add an error to the $errors array
        $errors[] = 'The file type is not allowed.';
      }

    //Delete the temporary file
    IF (file_exists ($_FILES['upload'] ['tmp_name']) && is_file($_FILES ['upload'] ['tmp_name'])) {
        unlink ($_FILES ['upload'] ['tmp_name']);
        echo '<p>The temp file been file.</p>';
    }
} else {

    print '<p>no file was uploaded</p>';
}
```

Comment: visit this : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Thanks, I've read that but unless I'm misunderstanding it only shows validation by file extension, so i could potentially upload a malicious file with the extension changed to .jpeg and it would pass the validation test. I'm looking for something a little more robust